# ARRAY_CONTAINS muliple values in hive

Tags: sql, hive

Is there a convenient way to use the ARRAY_CONTAINS function in hive to search for multiple entries in an array column rather than just one? So rather than:

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(array, val1) OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(array, val2)
```

I would like to write:

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(array, val1, val2)
```

The full problem is that I need to read `val1` and `val2` dynamically from the command line arguments when I run the script and I generally don't know how many values will be conditioned on. So you can think of `vals` being a comma separated list (or array) containing values `val1`, `val2`, `...`, and I want to write

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(array, vals)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a UDF [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/ArrayIntersectUDF.java) that will let you take the intersection of two arrays.  Assuming your values have the structure

```
values_array = [val1, val2, ..., valn]
```

You could then do

```
where array_intersection(array, values_array)[0] is not null
```

If they don't have any elements in common, `[]` will be returned and therefore `[][0]` will be `null`

Comment: I am in the same boat as the dynamo, is this still the best solution out there?

Comment: Ya I think this is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table tmp_cars AS  Select make,COLLECT_LIST(TRIM(model))
model_List from default.cars GROUP  BY make;

Select array_contains(model_List,CAST('Rainier' as varchar(40)))
FROM Default.tmp_cars t
where make = 'Buick';
```

Data

[" Rainier"," Rendezvous CX"," Century Custom 4dr"," LeSabre Custom 4dr"," Regal LS 4dr"," Regal GS 4dr"," LeSabre Limited 4dr"," Park Avenue 4dr"," Park Avenue Ultra 4dr"]

Return 
True

Answer (score -2):

select *
from table
lateral view explode(array) a as arr
where arr in (vals)
;