# How to filter on a string numpy array column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['a_b', 'bad'],['a_a', 'good'],[]]})
```

I would like to filter out all the rows for which `'bad'` is in the `list` of `col`

I have tried to first create a binary column and then filter on this one:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
foo = foo.withColumn('at_least_one_bad', f.when(f.col("col").array_contains("bad"),f.lit(1)).otherwise(f.lit(0)))
```

but I get an error

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off - try this code below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

foo2 = foo.withColumn('at_least_one_bad', f.array_contains('col', 'bad').cast('int'))

foo2.show()
+-----------+----------------+
|        col|at_least_one_bad|
+-----------+----------------+
| [a_b, bad]|               1|
|[a_a, good]|               0|
|         []|               0|
+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: is it possible to add multiple values in the `array_contains` ? for instance `'bad'` and `''` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538643/array-contains-muliple-values-in-pyspark